# create function for rendering text in one line

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function to render text on the screen in one line.

The below code is giving me a TypeError:

> ```
> TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not None
> ```

Essentially, I don't want to do something like
`textsurface = font.render("some text", False, (200, 200, 200)`
`screen.blit(text_surface, (100, 300)`

Would rather somehow be able to do it all in one line?

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```py
# Imports
import sys
import pygame

# Configuration
pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)

# System Font
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Garamond', 30)

def write_text(text,anti_alias,colour):
    font.render(text,anti_alias,colour)

# Game loop.
while  True:
    screen.fill((20, 20, 20))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(write_text('haloooo', False, (200, 200, 200)), (100, 300))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: You missed the `return` statement in the function

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I realised that write_text() wasn't returning anything...

The below now works as intended.

```py
def write_text(text,anti_alias,colour):
    return font.render(text,anti_alias,colour)
```